# Upload Image in Django with Ajax

Tags: django, ajax, form-data

This question is asked many times. And after long time trying I gave up.

I try to upload an image to the server with an Ajax function. The Ajax function does submit quite a lot of data (I deleted the unnecessary part).

The `console.log` gives me an empty array. What is wrong with my function?

Here is the HTML:

```
<form method="POST" id="form-create" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="file" id="myImg" name="myImg">

</form>
```

This is the script

```
$(document).on('submit', '#form-create', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()

    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('myIMG', $('#myIMG')[0]);
    console.log(formData)

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    url: "{% url 'creator:build' %}",
    data: {
         img:formData,
         csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
         },
            
         success: function (data){
              if (data.msg === "Success") {
                   $('h4').html('It worked!');
              }
                
              if (data.msg === 'Fail') {
                   $('h6').html('Sorry! There was a problem...');
              }
            },
        });
    });
```

Comment: Provide your views related to ajax call

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a HTMLInputElement to formdata.append, you should be passing a file

```
formData.append('myIMG', $('#myImg')[0].files[0]);
```

All fields you want to send in the ajax request body must be in the fromdata object

```
formData.append('csrfmiddlewaretoken',  $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val());
```

When making an $.ajax request with a formdata object you have to pass that as the data parameter and you also have to set processData and contentType to false

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    url: "{% url 'creator:build' %}",
    data: formData,  
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,          
    success: function (data){
          if (data.msg === "Success") {
               $('h4').html('It worked!');
          }
            
          if (data.msg === 'Fail') {
               $('h6').html('Sorry! There was a problem...');
          }
        },
    });
});
```

Comment: I get the following error message when I write `.files[0]`: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'files')"
And if I had the two lines `contentType: false` and `processData: false` the Ajax function does not work at all.

Comment: I updated the selector for the file input, apparently, ids are case-sensitive in the selector. `contentType` and `processData` being set to false are necessary for the request.